# Macro on a button that delete the merge rows its on

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I have a form that insert 5 rows of data  which span from column "A" to "V" with some merged. I had my macro which inserted this 5 rows insert a button at "V" and merge the 5 rows so that the button would land on all 5 rows. I need to give a function to this button so that it can delete all 5 rows of data. This function needs to take reference from where it is and delete the next 4 rows.

I don't really know excel VBA so I can only describe what I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you need a code to delete the last row (from column A to column V) filled in the sheet?

Comment: Basically I need it to delete all 5 rows
Col A's 5 rows are merged
Col B have 5 different row of values
Col V 5 rows are merged and has the delete button which is supposed to delete the 5 rows.

I have a userform that inserts the five rows every time it is submitted

Comment: I edited the code below to delete the last 5 rows

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What if i want the button to delete the merged rows its on rather than last 5 rows. Basically now im using topleftcell.entirerow. But it only delets the first row of the 5

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of rows already occupied in column A and then select the last row to delete it. In the code, you need to change what I have called "SheetName" to the actual name of your excel sheet.

```
Sub Delet_LastRow()
    
    'r = number of filled rows from A1 to A100000
    r = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("SheetName").Range("A1:A100000"))
    'Select the sheet named "SheetName"
    Sheets("SheetName").Select
    'select last 5 rows from column A to column V and delete them
    Range(Cells(r-5, "A").Address(), Cells(r, "V").Address()).Select
    Selection.Delete

End Sub
```